# Is there a way to scrape tweets in realtime from a list of specified users?

Tags: data-mining, scraping, web-scraping, crawling

I am trying to build a scraper that will run continuously and save the tweets from a list of users instantaneously or within seconds of the user tweeting it. It could save the tweet details to a continuously updated csv file.

Comment: this is appropriate for stackoverflow as it is about twitter API and not about ML per se